# C# Regex for file names with extension

Tags: c#, regex

I suck at Regex but I need one that would understand the form of a file with its extension
which is:
Anycharacter.threecharachter extension
Im fine with something like *.*  if the compiler gets it

I tried

```
Regex ex = new regex(".*\\..*")
```

and

```
Regex ex = new regex(".*\\....");
```

Example that should pass:

```
 ex.IsMatch("test.zip");
```

Thanks for the note @Alice;
I changed my code the filebrowser now shows:
-rwxr-x---   1 root      nto            1007 Jan 10 14:28 chat.sh

OR

drwxr-x---   1 root      nto            1007 Jan 10 14:28 accounts

OR

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root      nto               9 Jan 15 06:43 lib -> /base/lib

The d is what defines the directory at the beginning of the line.
I wanna read such a line and get in return

bool Isdirectory;

string fName;

Comment: also take into consideration hidden files starting with .filename
Those are not to to pass Regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    string x = "drwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users        0 Nov 30  2011 VSWebCache";
    Match m = Regex.Match(x, @"^(?<dir>d)?.*?(?<name>\w+(?:\.\w{3})?)$");

    if(m.Success)
    {
        string name = m.Groups["name"].Value;
        bool isDir = m.Groups["dir"].Success;
    }
```

"name" is now a string containing the filename or directory name.
"isDir" now contains a bool whether the listing starts with "d" for directory or not.

Your regex is as follows:

```
^(?<dir>d)?.*?(?<name>\w+(?:\.\w{3})?)$
```

It is saying this:
Create 2 groups named "dir" and "name".  If starts with "d" then group "dir" will contain "d".  Group "name" will contain either the file name or directory name.  There is some play in the name as it will match a "filename" and "filename.ext" if a "." exists in the name.

This will also work if

```
string x = @"-rwx------+ 1 Administrators Domain Users    72080 Dec 16  2011 g2mdlhlpx.exe";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[^\.]    //Not a period once
.*       //Anything 0..more times
\.       //Period
.{1,3}   //Anything, up to three times
```

All together:

```
[^\.].*\..{1,3}
```

If the entire line/text has to match, put it in `^$`:

```
^[^\.].*\..{1,3}$
```

Note that files without extensions are also valid filenames, so you may need to relax the period `.` requirement at some point :) Plus, period matches symbols that aren't valid in a filename, like `*`, `/`, etc. so you may be asking the wrong question here.

EDIT:
Now that you added the flags, the question makes more sense. It is very easy to do the new check:

```
if( line.StartsWith( "d" ) )
    return true; //It's a directory.
```

Comment: @abdul: There isn't any way to distinguish folder names with a regex. Folder names can have a file extension, too; there is no prohibition against a folder name such as "example.abc".

Comment: @abdul it doesn't match `root` (see [here](http://ideone.com/s23Jur)). However I think this isn't your real problem. See David's comment - you *can't* distinguish between a folder and a file using a regex. Files and folders' names follow exactly the same rules.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
^.*\.[^.]{3}$
```

---

If you want to match a particular character n number of times you can use `{}` quantifier

so `.{3}` would match three characters

`x{2}` would match 2 x

`x{1,5}` would match 1 to 5 x

Comment: It did not match on 2013X.zip !!

Comment: @abdul the above regex would match only if there is only one `2013X.zip` it wont work for multiple filenames in the input...show us the code and the input you are using

Answer (score 0):

This is the file name Regex I use for windows file names

```
^[^/\\:*""<>|]+?\.\w{1,3}$
```

These symbols`^/\:*"<>|` represent the disallowed character for file names on windows.

If you dont want more than one period in your file name you can use this one:

```
^[^/\\:*""<>|.]+?\.\w{1,3}$
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
.+\.(.{1,3})+
```

`.+` will look for file name, and will make sure that file name contains at least 1 character. `\.` will look for a period. `.{1,3}` will look for extension that could be one to three characters long. `(.{1,3})+` will take care of file names that have extensions like filename.tar.gz.

so the regex will validate filename.z, filename.gz, filename.zip, filename.tar.gz, etc.

Comment: What would happen if the file name were source.tar.gz?

Comment: let me make an edit to my answer. Hope that would take care of these sort of file names as well.

Comment: This would match a file named `.ext`, which the OP said should *not* match.

Comment: it passes on folder names as well !!

Comment: if you could please let me know the exact string of these folder names.